# Android Getting Multiple Pins on Map from Database

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I have SQlite DB where currently i have 4 values of La/Long and Names 
I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview#top) link, but no help on getting multiple pins from DB 
I want to get multiple pins on the MapView and My Main Class i have done this coding :

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.tabhost.MyTabHostProvider;
import com.example.tabhost.TabHostProvider;
import com.example.tabhost.TabView;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;


public class MapViewActivity extends MapActivity{

private MapView mapView;
public ArrayList lati,longi;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TabHostProvider tabProvider = new MyTabHostProvider(MapViewActivity.this);
    TabView tabView = tabProvider.getTabHost("Map");
    tabView.setCurrentView(R.layout.map);
    setContentView(tabView.render(2));
     mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);
     mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


     DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        // --- Cursor Coding

        Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.getAllContacts();
          //  int a = cursor.getCount();
          //    Log.d("GH:", String.valueOf(a));
            String[] names = cursor.getColumnNames();  
            System.out.print(names[1]);
            Log.v("Name :", names[3]);

             lati = new ArrayList();
             longi = new ArrayList();

                String latitudes = "";
                String longitudes = "";
                String result = "";


for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){

                latitudes = latitudes + cursor.getDouble(3) + "\n";
                    longitudes = longitudes + cursor.getDouble(4) + "\n";
                result = result + cursor.getString(2) + "\n";
               //   Log.d("Latitude222 :", latitudes);

                }
lati.add(latitudes);
longi.add(longitudes);

int b = lati.size(); // returns 1
Log.d("Size :", String.valueOf(b));



//   List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    // Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    // MapItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


        for (int i=0; i<b; i++){

//          Log.d("Hello :", String.valueOf(al.get(i)));
            Log.d("Hello :", (String) lati.get(i));



            // GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(35410000, 139460000);
        //   OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Hi!", "I'm in Japan!");




            // itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);

        }

            Log.d("Hello22 :", (String) lati.get(0));   // here i am getting all the 4 values of latitude at zero index :(
    //   GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble((String) lati.get(1)) * 1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble((String) longi.get(1)) * 1E6));
        // OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello!", "I'm in Mexico City!");
    //   itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    //  mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay); 

         cursor.close();
      // ---- End Cursor coding 
        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }



    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }



}
```

My DB Helper class has this code

```
 ...............    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

private DataBaseHelper ourHelper;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}   



/**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{


    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        Log.v("DB:", "Exist");
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{
        Log.v("DB:", "Else is called");
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            Log.v("DB:", "copy DB");
            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Log.v("DB:", "Opened");
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        Log.v("DB:", "Closed");
        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public Cursor getAllContacts()
{
return myDataBase.query("Points", new String[] {"_id", "p_id", "name", "latitude", "longitude"},
null, null, null, null, null);
}
}
```

And My MapItemizedOverlay Class is like this:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MapItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

Context mContext;

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

public MapItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return mOverlays.get(i);
//  return null;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.size();
    // return 0;
}

public MapItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
      mContext = context;
    }

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}
  }
```

Please Can any one tell me what corrections i need to make in my Main Map class to get all the pins on MapView.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<CustomItem> {
        private View view = null;
        private List<CustomItem> items = new ArrayList<CustomItem>();

        public SitesOverlay() {
            super(null);

                // array list = yout lat and long array size
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                    slat = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(i).getLat());
                    vlong = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(i).getvLong());
                    pt = new GeoPoint((int) (slat * 1E6), (int) (vlong * 1E6));
                    Log.e("lat long", "--- "+slat);
                    MapviewActivity.this.mc.animateTo(pt);
                    items.add(new CustomItem(pt, arrayList.get(i).getBuissnessName(), "Bendigo", marker));
                    boundCenter(marker);


populate();
        }
```

set lat and long as shown above code in your MapItemizedOverlay class

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
do{
// YOUR CODE FOR EACH CURSOR ITEM HERE.
// the cursor moves one field at a time trhough it's whole dataset
}while(c.moveToNext())
}
```

Comment: you mean i have to do it in MapItemizedOverlay class and nothing in my MainMap Class ...

Comment: in your map activity just set mapView.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay());

Comment: but their is some problem while getting value from DB ... It stores all the 4 values at zero index of Arraylist .. as you can see if you go through my code of main map activity class ..

Comment: use do while and before this add this line cursor.moveToFirst().

Comment: if(c.moveToFirst()){
do{
// YOUR CODE FOR EACH CURSOR ITEM HERE.
/
}while(c.moveToNext())
}

Comment: do i need to use CustomItem istead of OverlayItem .. i am trying to follow http://kyogs.blogspot.in/ ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28103/discussion-between-iosbee-and-moj-ma-ho)

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you in this function pass your Latitude and Longitude

```
    for(int j= 0;j<arrofLatLOng.size();j++) {

       String  checklat = "your latitude"    
       String   checklon = "your longitude"

                 point = new GeoPoint((int) ((Double.parseDouble(checklat) * 1E6)),(int)((Double.parseDouble(checklon)) * 1E6));
                 Log.i(tag, "Geo Point is...."+point);
                  overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,checktitle,checksdateformate);             
                  abc = imgloader.getBitmap(checkimg);
                  d = new BitmapDrawable(abc);
                  itemizedoverlay = new CheckInMapItemizedOverlay(d,mapview,true,streventid);
                  itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                  mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
                  mapController.animateTo(point);             

    }
```